# Eigen rowwise cross product between arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, eigen

I have two `Eigen::ArrayX3d` objects, that's N rows and 3 columns. To make this concrete, the first array consists of 3d velocities of N particles. The other one consists of magnetic field vectors at the position of each of the particles. I'm trying to compute the Lorentz force, `v x B` - this means I have to take each pair of rows and compute the cross product. In Python, this would mean simply doing `numpy.cross(v, B)`.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in `Eigen` and failing hard. It seems as though `cross` is defined for `Matrix` and `Vector`s only, but it doesn't really make sense to me to keep my data as a `Matrix` (though I'm of course open to suggestions).

Is there any reasonable way to perform this operation? I'd be very grateful for any pointers.

This setup is a good example::

```
   ArrayX3d a(4,3);  
   ArrayX3d b(4,3);
   a <<1,0,0,
       0,1,0,
       0,0,1,
       1,0,0;
   b <<0,1,0,
       0,0,1,
       1,0,0,
       0,1,0;
```

A successful application of the **a x b** operation should just shift the 1's by 1 place to the right in each row.

Comment: You can see any `Array` as a matrix or vector using `.matrix()`. This way you get access to the cross product function.

Comment: Sure, but that's not really helpful because I can't do `v.matrix().cross(B.matrix())`. I'm not trying to do this "between entire arrays", but row-wise. I've tried doing messing around with `.rowwise()`, but it hasn't been working out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the result using a matrix or array:

```
  MatrixX3d a(4, 3);
  MatrixX3d b(4, 3);
  a << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0;
  b << 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < a.rows(); i++){
      cout << a.row(i).cross(b.row(i)) << endl;
  }
```

With an array:

```
  ArrayX3d a(4, 3);
  ArrayX3d b(4, 3);
  a << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0;
  b << 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < a.rows(); i++){
      cout << a.row(i).matrix().cross(b.matrix().row(i)) << endl;
  }
```

The output:

```
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

This result could be saved into a matrix or array for each row.

Comment: This does seem to be the only way to do it. Feels kind of like a limitation of the library, doesn't it?

Comment: It seems that the loop cannot be avoided if the `.cross()` function is used. It would be nice to have the possibility to combine the member functions `.rowwise().cross()`, but that doesn't seem to work with the current version of Eigen.

Comment: Yep this kind of sucks because it precludes parallel cross products. Looking at the implementation of `cross()` there is a `EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_SPECIFIC_SIZE` assertion that enforces one of the dimensions to be 1 and the other to be 3 for both operands so you have to perform the cross products on the individual vectors.